# Mapreduce help for plotting linegraph

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, sails.js

I am working on SAILSJS Project, Having some issue while generating data for Graphical Line Chart from the below data.

```
   [{   "_id" : "575fcb020d28bbc117647c7a",  "childid" : "575a4952bfb2ad01481e9060",  "starttime" : "1465895783",  "endtime" : "1465895783",  "word" : "TOE",  "gamescore" : "1",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-14T09:14:42.959Z"
    },
    { "_id" : "575fcbd150c93cf819faecfe",  "childid" : "575a4952bfb2ad01481e9060", "starttime" : "1465895983",  "endtime" : "1465895990",  "word" : "SLOW",   "gamescore" : "1",   "createdAt" : "2016-06-14T09:18:09.453Z"
    },
    {"_id" : "575fcbd150c93cf819faecff", "childid" : "575a4952bfb2ad01481e9060","starttime" : "1465895959",  "endtime" : "1465895959",  "word" : "GLOW",  "gamescore" : "1",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-14T09:18:09.454Z"
    },
    { "_id" : "57619851d71451e56949dd4d",  "starttime" : "1466013832",  "gamescore" : "1", "childid" : "5761973fd71451e56949dd3c",  "endtime" : "1466013850",  "word" : "YUM",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-15T18:02:57.543Z"
    },
    { "_id" : "576198ead71451e56949dd58",  "starttime" : "1466014023",  "gamescore" : "1",  "childid" : "5761973fd71451e56949dd3c",  "endtime" : "1466014030",  "word" : "BELT",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-15T18:05:30.945Z"
    },
    {  "_id" : "57619915d71451e56949dd5f", "childid" : "576197c2d71451e56949dd40",  "starttime" : "1466013984",  "endtime" : "1466013989",  "word" : "PLAY",  "gamescore" : "1",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-15T18:06:13.388Z"
    },
   { "_id" : "57619958d71451e56949dd65",  "starttime" : "1466014140",  "gamescore" : "1",  "childid" : "5761973fd71451e56949dd3c",  "endtime" : "1466014143",  "word" : "BELL",  "createdAt" : "2016-06-15T18:07:20.298Z"
      }............]
```

I am looking for help on making time interval of 4 Hrs for a single day and grouping of gamescore correct is "1" and gamescore wrong is "0" something below like.

For the below Output, I used Aggregation to get this for interval of 4 hrs of each day in between two dates. but if there is no gamescore records for particular period, for that period data points are not created as i am expecting datapoint and gmscore are 0 reflecting in that.

**Expected Output with 4 intervals of each day of two dates**

```
   [{ "txnTime" : ISODate("2016-06-10T04:00:00.000Z"),"gmScoreCorrectCount" : 15, "gmScoreWrongCount" : 2 },
   { "txnTime" : ISODate("2016-06-10T08:00:00.000Z"),"gmScoreCorrectCount" : 10, "gmScoreWrongCount" : 8 },
   { "txnTime" : ISODate("2016-06-13T04:00:00.000Z"),"gmScoreCorrectCount" : 9, "gmScoreWrongCount" : 9 },
   { "txnTime" : ISODate("2016-06-14T04:00:00.000Z"),"gmScoreCorrectCount" : 7, "gmScoreWrongCount" : 8 },
   { "txnTime" : ISODate("2016-06-14T08:00:00.000Z"),"gmScoreCorrectCount" : 6, "gmScoreWrongCount" : 7 }]
```

I am pretty new with using mapreduce, but i know it can be achieved with mapreduce:

```
    mapf = function () { 
// round down to nearest hour
d = this.createdAt;
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
emit(d, this.gamescore); 
 }

   reducef = function (key, values) {
var sum = 0;
for (var v in values) {
    sum += values;
}
return sum;
  }

     db.activity.mapReduce(mapf, reducef, {out: { merge : "hourly_logs" }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me note that your sample input is not coherent with the sample output you gave.

Having that, a possible solution using map-reduce to solve the problem can be:

```
mapf = function () { 

    d = new Date(this.createdAt);

    // bucket every 4 hours
    d.setHours(d.getHours()-(d.getHours()%4));

    // remove minutes, seconds and milis from date
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    d.setMilliseconds(0);

    gscore = parseInt(this.gamescore);

    gmScoreCorrectCount = 0;
    gmScoreWrongCount = 0;
    if(gscore > 0){
        gmScoreCorrectCount += 1;
    }else{
        gmScoreWrongCount += 1;
    }

    emit(d, {"gmScoreCorrectCount": gmScoreCorrectCount, "gmScoreWrongCount": gmScoreWrongCount});
}

reducef = function (key, values) {

    var gmScoreCorrectCount = 0;
    var gmScoreWrongCount = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        v = values[i]
        gmScoreCorrectCount += v['gmScoreCorrectCount'];
        gmScoreWrongCount += v['gmScoreWrongCount'];

    }
    return {"gmScoreCorrectCount": gmScoreCorrectCount, "gmScoreWrongCount": gmScoreWrongCount};
}
```

The missing results injection step needs to be done outside, in the client side:

```
res = db.activity.mapReduce(mapf, reducef, {out: { inline: 1 }})['results'];

var correctResult;
if(res.length > 1){

    // sort results by created
    res.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a._id) - parseFloat(b._id);
    });

    correctResult = [res[0]];

    referenceDate = res[0]['_id'];
    for(var ri = 1; ri<res.length; ri++){

        diff = res[ri]['_id'] - referenceDate;

        // 14400000 milis = 4 hours
        if (diff > 14400000){

            numberOfMissing = Math.ceil((diff - 14400000)/14400000);

            // inject missing values
            for(var ni=1; ni <= numberOfMissing; ni++){
                correctResult.push({"_id": new Date(referenceDate.getTime()+(14400000*ni)), "value": {"gmScoreCorrectCount": 0, "gmScoreWrongCount": 0}});
            }

        }

        correctResult.push(res[ri]);

        referenceDate = res[ri]['_id'];

    }

}else{

    correctResult = res;

}
```

Note that the emit value must follow the reduced value format because *the reduce function must be idempotent*. [Read more about it here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/).

Besides the asked question, I have some remarks regarding your data that complicates processing and querying. First, don't save numbers (like the gamescore) as strings. The same goes for dates and timestamps (mongo has DATE objects, so you should strive to use them).

Comment: Hi @joao, Thanks for your inputs, First i apolosize for my poor english. The above produced answer is correct but partially, the main issue over here is, I need 4 hours interval irrespective of "createdAt", as the above answer will not give if no data available at that interval. How can i over come that. looking for your reply.

Comment: @chridam, Please look into it.

Comment: @AyyappaA to add the missing values you need to inject them yourself in the client side. There is no way to do it in the map-reduce step.

Comment: @AyyappaA I added some sample code showing how you can inject the missing values in javascript. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your response made my day. joao.